# Is it okay to have multiple url patterns with the same view?

Tags: django

I have an app that shows a list of "Issues". The main urls.py file sends /issues/ to the urls.py file in the "issues" app.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/issues/')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('issues/', include('issues.urls')),
]
```

In the issues app's urls.py file I have:

```
path('', views.IssueListView.as_view(), name='issue-list'),
```

That calls the IssueListView which is a generic ListView view:

```
class IssueListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Issue
```

Now, I want to add a sidebar menu with links users can click to sort the issues list by category. I understand that I can rewrite the get_queryset() method of the IssueListView to accept a  kwarg, and just load all the issues if that kwarg is missing (with an if statement that checks for the presence of the kwarg, right?), but I think to do this I need to have two urlpatterns that point to the same view like:

```
path('', views.IssueListView.as_view(), name='issue-list'),
path('<category>', views.IssueListView.as_view(), name='issue-category-list'),
```

But I am wondering if that's the normal "Django way" to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you have specified, you can use the same view for both `url pattern`. There is nothing wrong in that.

```
path('', views.IssueListView.as_view(), name='issue-list'),
path('<category>', views.IssueListView.as_view(), name='issue-category-list'),
```